# aspx: Setting message selector on Active MQ message

Tags: asp.net, activemq-classic, selector

I have a simple test website, written in ASP.NET (C#), from which I can send messages to an Active MQ queue on my local host, and receive message from a queue on local host. My question here is two-folded:

1) How can I send a message from my website to the Queue that contains a specific Selector value?

At the moment I create the message I'm sending to the queue like this:

```
IConnectionFactory factory = new NMSConnectionFactory("tcp://192.168.1.152:61616");
        IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        connection.Start();

        ISession session = connection.CreateSession(AcknowledgementMode.AutoAcknowledge);
        IDestination QueueDestination = SessionUtil.GetDestination(session, "Request");
        IMessageProducer messageProducer = session.CreateProducer(QueueDestination);

        ITextMessage request = session.CreateTextMessage(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + ": " + tb_Request.Text.Trim());
        messageProducer.Send(request);
```

2) When creating a message on my Local host ActiveMQ queue, how do I add selector values to the message?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

Message selectors are a way for consumers (subscriptions) to filter the messages that they receive when active.  You do no set or do anything with a selector on send of a message.  If you send to a Queue and a consumer has a selector that matches the message then it will be dispatched to it, otherwise the message will remain on the Queue until another consumer reads and acknowledges it.  Some documentation is [here](http://activemq.apache.org/selectors.html).

Do some searching on Google for JMS Message Selectors to learn more.

Comment: From the link you refer to, and others I have looked at, you have to give the consumer selector as a key/value pair. What I am having difficulties with is where to put this key/value pair in the message.

Can anyone tell me where and how in the message the selector key/value pair should be placed?

Comment: Your original question doesn't reflect what you seem to now be asking, I'd update the question to make it clear.

Comment: My apologies if my question was unclear to begin with. Thanks for taking the time to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figured it out, and thought that I would share my findings here for others to see/comment.

First I created an OperatorRequestObject class:

```
public class OperatorRequestObject
{
    string shortcode;

    public string Shortcode {
        get { return shortcode; }
        set { shortcode = value; }
    }
}
```

When creating the message to send to the queue I used this code:

```
OperatorRequestObject OperatorRequestObject = new OperatorRequestObject();
        OperatorRequestObject.Shortcode = tb_Request.Text.ToString();

        IConnectionFactory factory = new NMSConnectionFactory("tcp://192.XXX.X.XXX:61616");
        IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        connection.Start();

        ISession session = connection.CreateSession(AcknowledgementMode.AutoAcknowledge);
        IDestination QueueDestination = SessionUtil.GetDestination(session, "Command");
        IMessageProducer messageProducer = session.CreateProducer(QueueDestination);

        ITextMessage request = session.CreateTextMessage(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + ": " + tb_Request.Text.Trim());
        request.Properties.SetString("deviceID", "12345");
        messageProducer.Send(request);

        session.Close();
        connection.Stop();

        tb_Request.Text = "";
        tb_Request.Focus();
```

The line "request.Properties.SetString("deviceID", "12345");" is where I add my selector key/value pair, that I use to select which consumer get what message.

To retrieve the message based on the value of "deviceID" I use this code:

```
string Selector = "deviceID = '12345'";
        IConnectionFactory factory = new NMSConnectionFactory("tcp://192.XXX.X.XXX:61616");
        IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        connection.Start();
        ISession session = connection.CreateSession(AcknowledgementMode.AutoAcknowledge);

        IDestination destination = SessionUtil.GetDestination(session, "Command");
        IMessageConsumer messageConsumer = session.CreateConsumer(destination, Selector);

        IMessage message = messageConsumer.Receive();

        string NewCommand = "";

        if (message != null) {
            ITextMessage IText = message as ITextMessage;
            if (IText != null) {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(IText.Text)) {
                    NewCommand = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + ": " + IText.Text;
                }
            }
        }
        tb_Command.Text = tb_Command.Text + "\r\n" + NewCommand;
        messageConsumer.Close();
        messageConsumer.Dispose();
        connection.Stop();
        connection.Close();
        connection.Dispose();
```

Setting the "string Selector = "deviceID = '12345'" (don't forget the ' ') means the consumer only takes messages from the queue that were send using the selector shown above.

***PLEASE NOTE:*** The code above is most likely not "best practice" or as fast and compact as it could be. This is simply how I managed to get my code to work.

Hope this helps someone with the same problem.

Feel free to comment :-)